# js coding newbie - having trouble with variables and for loops

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, highcharts

I'm using Netbeans 8.0, Primefaces 4.0, Highcharts, Java, and XHTML.

Eventually, I will want to load data that is grabbed dynamically from a database and loaded onto a web app, but first, I need to figure out how to generate a chart using a for loop. The example I'm attempting to modify is the [basic line chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo) example on Highcharts.

My code looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

            <f:facet name="first">
                <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
                <title>PrimeFaces</title>
            </f:facet>
        </h:head>

        <h:body>

            <p:layout fullPage="true">

                <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                    Header
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                    Footer
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="175" header="Left" collapsible="true">
                    <p:menu>
                        <p:submenu label="Resources">
                            <p:menuitem value="Demo" url="http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/home.jsf" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Documentation" url="http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Forum" url="http://forum.primefaces.org/" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Themes" url="http://www.primefaces.org/themes.html" />

                        </p:submenu>

                    </p:menu>
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="center">

                    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

                </p:layoutUnit>

            </p:layout>

        </h:body>

    </f:view>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
 // <![CDATA[
 function() {

        cityArray = #{tokyoBean.cityArr},
                tempsArray = #{tokyoBean.cityArrArr},
                monthsArray = #{tokyoBean.catArr},
                series = []
                ,
                len = cityArray.length;
                for (var i = 0; i &#60; len; i++)
        {
        series.push({
        name: [cityArray[i]],
                data: [tempsArray[i]]
        });
        }
        $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: - 20 //center
        },
                subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                        x: - 20
                },
                xAxis: {
                categories: monthsArray
                },
                yAxis: {
                title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                        plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                                width: 1,
                                color: '#808080'
                        }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
                },
                legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'middle',
                        borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: series
        }),
        };
// ]]>
    </script>
</html>
```

When I run the file and view the page source, the code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
                <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
                <title>PrimeFaces</title><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Demo/faces/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-aristo" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Demo/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Demo/faces/javax.faces.resource/layout/layout.css?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/Demo/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/Demo/faces/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/Demo/faces/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/Demo/faces/javax.faces.resource/layout/layout.js?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script></head><body><script id="j_idt6_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('Layout','widget_j_idt6',{id:'j_idt6',full:true,north:{paneSelector:'#j_idt7',size:'100',resizable:true,closable:true,spacing_open:6,spacing_closed:25},south:{paneSelector:'#j_idt9',size:'100',resizable:false,closable:true,spacing_open:6,spacing_closed:25},west:{paneSelector:'#j_idt11',size:'175',resizable:false,closable:true,spacing_open:6,spacing_closed:25},center:{paneSelector:'#j_idt18',size:'auto',resizable:false,closable:false}},'layout');});</script><div id="j_idt7" class="ui-layout-unit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-layout-north"><div class="ui-layout-unit-content ui-widget-content">
                    Header
                </div></div><div id="j_idt9" class="ui-layout-unit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-layout-south"><div class="ui-layout-unit-content ui-widget-content">
                    Footer
                </div></div><div id="j_idt11" class="ui-layout-unit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-layout-west"><div class="ui-layout-unit-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-layout-unit-header-title">Left</span><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ui-layout-unit-header-icon ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title="Collapse"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-w"></span></a></div><div class="ui-layout-unit-content ui-widget-content"><div id="j_idt12" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" role="menu"><div tabindex="0" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></div><ul class="ui-menu-list ui-helper-reset"><li class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all"><h3>Resources</h3></li><li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem"><a tabindex="-1" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/home.jsf"><span class="ui-menuitem-text">Demo</span></a></li><li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem"><a tabindex="-1" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html"><span class="ui-menuitem-text">Documentation</span></a></li><li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem"><a tabindex="-1" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="http://forum.primefaces.org/"><span class="ui-menuitem-text">Forum</span></a></li><li class="ui-menuitem ui-widget ui-corner-all" role="menuitem"><a tabindex="-1" class="ui-menuitem-link ui-corner-all" href="http://www.primefaces.org/themes.html"><span class="ui-menuitem-text">Themes</span></a></li></ul></div><script id="j_idt12_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('PlainMenu','widget_j_idt12',{id:'j_idt12'});});</script></div></div><div id="j_idt18" class="ui-layout-unit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-layout-center"><div class="ui-layout-unit-content ui-widget-content">

                    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div></div></div><ul id="javax_faces_developmentstage_messages" title="Project Stage[Development]: Unhandled Messages"><li style="Color: orange"><span>        The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within &lt;h:form&gt; </span></li><li style="Color: orange"><span>      The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within &lt;h:form&gt; </span></li></ul></body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
 // <![CDATA[
 function() {

        cityArray = ['Tokyo', 'New York', 'Berlin', 'London'],
                tempsArray = [[7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6], [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5], [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0], [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 6.6]],
                monthsArray = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
                series = []
                ,
                len = cityArray.length;
                for (var i = 0; i &#60; len; i++)
        {
        series.push({
        name: [cityArray[i]],
                data: [tempsArray[i]]
        });
        }
        $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: - 20 //center
        },
                subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                        x: - 20
                },
                xAxis: {
                categories: monthsArray
                },
                yAxis: {
                title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                        plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                                width: 1,
                                color: '#808080'
                        }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
                },
                legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'middle',
                        borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: series
        }),
        };
// ]]>
    </script>
</html>
```

And I can't post a ss of what my page looks like, but it is almost completely blank except 
at the bottom it says:

"       The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within 
    The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within  "

in big, yellow letters.

Please explain what I'm doing wrong. I have another version of this page which does not employ the for loop, but instead calls data arrays from the backing bean for each city - that version works fine, but I won't be able to do that in final implementation since all data will have to be pulled dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

I've been working on this all afternoon and have made some real headway, but I'm still not quite there. The Netbeans editor won't allow for formatting the series.push() method the way I was trying to use it, and also, I had to declare and define variables on separate lines of code to get them to stick, so to speak. I removed my jquery script source (which got rid of the yellow warning messages), and my code now looks like this:

```
    //html code redacted as it is working

    <script>
        $(function() {

            cityArray = new Array();
            cityArray = #{tokyoBean.cityArr};
            monthsArray = new Array();
            monthsArray = #{tokyoBean.catArr};
            tempsArray = new Array();
            tempsArray = #{tokyoBean.cityArrArr};
            len = cityArray.length;
            series = new Array();

for(i=0; i &#60; len; i++) {
    series.push("{ <br /> name: "+[cityArray[i]]+", <br /> data: "+[tempsArray[i]]+" <br /> } ");
}



            $('#container').highcharts({
                title: {
                    text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: monthsArray
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '°C'
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: series
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Running this file now renders the title, subtitle, legend, horizontal and vertical axis, but still not the plot itself. Any clues?

Comment: Don't know if this is related with your issue, but when looking at primefaces' `p:menu` [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menu.xhtml), you'll notice it's enclosed by a `h:form` element. But yours isn't.

Comment: in the for loop, you have `&#60;` when it should be <

Comment: Unrelated, have you checked if Primefaces chart satisfies your needs? Its pretty neat for standard stuff, although I ran into problems with logarithmic axis in 4.0. But it has gotten an overhaul for 5.0 if you need that: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/line.xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me say thank you for everyone who offered suggestions. I played with code and finally got it to work. Just in case anyone has this problem again, here is what my final xhtml and js code looks like.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script> 
            <f:facet name="first">
                <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
                <title>PrimeFaces</title>
            </f:facet>
        </h:head>

        <h:body>

            <p:layout fullPage="true">

                <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                    Header
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                    Footer
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="175" header="Left" collapsible="true">
                    <p:menu>
                        <p:submenu label="Resources">
                            <p:menuitem value="Demo" url="http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/home.jsf" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Documentation" url="http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Forum" url="http://forum.primefaces.org/" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Themes" url="http://www.primefaces.org/themes.html" />

                        </p:submenu>

                    </p:menu>
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="center">

                    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

                </p:layoutUnit>

            </p:layout>

        </h:body>

    </f:view>

    <script>
        $(function() {

            cityArray = new Array();
            cityArray = #{tokyoBean.cityArr};
            monthsArray = new Array();
            monthsArray = #{tokyoBean.catArr};
            tempsArray = new Array();
            tempsArray = #{tokyoBean.cityArrArr};
            len = cityArray.length;
            series = new Array();

            for(i=0; i &#60; len; i++) {
                var arrayElement = tempsArray[i],
                        cityElement = cityArray[i];
                series.push({
                    name: cityElement,
                    data: arrayElement
                });
            }




            $('#container').highcharts({
                title: {
                    text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: monthsArray
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: '°C'
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: series
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```